# MySQL Connector/C++ Example code is not working

Tags: c++, mysql

Hello i've just started using C++ MySql Connector in appication 
Release|Win3

My Errors:

> Warning   1   warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking
>   for precompiled header use    c:\Documents and Settings...
>
> Warning   2   warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking
>   for precompiled header use    c:\Documents and Settings...
>
> Error 3   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'boost/variant.hpp': No such file or directory    C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++
>   1.1.0\include\cppconn\connection.h    29  lacznik

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
    {



cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you please properly indent your code? I do not want to waste my voluntary time on tracking scopes mentally.

Comment: This Code is  from     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html    I'm not sure abut y library. Here is  my tree  http://www.wgraj.org/uploads/photos/simple/screen_6adc371c220e99f428fd221552609358.JPG

Comment: Apart from the formatting issues: What have you tried already? What specifically are you having problems with? Did you read the FAQ and posting guidelines? As is, this is not really a question.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning 1 warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use c:\Documents and Settings...

means that the "precompiled header" include

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

should be the first header included.

Comment: As an addendum to this, by default all (unmanaged at least) C++ projects in Visual Studio are using pre-compiled headers. In such a project, _all_ source files _must_ include `"stdafx.h"` as the first include, or get the same errors as the OP.